# Reschedulable Callable

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, future, executorservice

I am using a `ScheduledExecutorService` to execute callables after a given delay, I want to make these repeatable so i created the following class

```
class ReschedulableCallable<V> implements Callable<V> {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService;
   private final Callable<V> callable;

   public ReschedulableCallable(
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService, Callable<V> callable) {
    this.executorService = executorService;
    this.callable = callable;
    executorService.schedule(this, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }

   @Override
   public V call() throws Exception {
      try {
         return callable.call();
      } finally {
         executorService.schedule(this, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     }
  }
}
```

but the callable is only executable once not repeated like i need, even i am initializing it after is called, also please dont say use `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate` or `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay` as i want it to return with generic type, so why is this?

Comment: `ScheduledExecutorService` allows scheduling repeated tasks using [`scheduleWithFixedDelay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

Comment: Does scheduling a different/new `Callable` object every time work?

Comment: I think that yesterday I might have missed the problem completely: are you sure that your callable is executed just once? Or is it more that you only get the result of the first call? Because with your method, you only return the `ScheduledFuture` of the first invocation, return values of all subsequent invocations are ignored (in the finally-block).

Answer (score 2):

The API doesn't allow scheduling a recurring `Callable` because a `Future` can only change states one time. There's no way to return the results of subsequent executions, thus, no point in using something other than `Runnable`. The generic type of the `Future` resulting from the recurring APIs is unbound because its `get()` method will never return a result; can only be used to cancel the recurring task.

The code you have written *does* execute the `Callable` repeatedly, but it only returns the result of the first execution. Again, `Future` is a one-shot.

Instead, use a `Runnable` with the appropriate fixed rate or fixed delay API. Do whatever you want to do with the "result" inside your task itself. The task could offer something like a callback to decouple consumption of the "result" from its production, which is implemented currently in your `Callable`.

Here's a rough example:

```java
final class Task<V> implements Runnable {

    private final Supplier<? extends V> producer;
    private final Consumer<? super V> consumer;

    Task(Supplier<? extends V> producer, Consumer<? super V> consumer) {
        this.producer = Objects.requireNonNull(producer);
        this.consumer = Objects.requireNonNull(consumer);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        V result = producer.get();
        consumer.accept(result);
    }

    public static void main(String... arg) {
        Runnable task = new Task<>(() -> "Hello, World!", System.out::println);
        ScheduledExecutorService worker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        Future<?> cancellable = worker.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 1L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(8L);
        cancellable.cancel(false);
        System.out.println("Canceled");
        worker.shutdown();
    }

}
```

You might choose to handle errors from the producer, consumer, or both. An additional callback could be added for that. Implementations might log, alert, stop the task, etc. (In that case, you might use `Callable` in place of `Supplier`.)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate` or `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay` - one of both will do what you need probably. (You don't need to implement this for yourself, your own implementation probably won't behave as you want if you get it to work, especially in edge cases or with critical timing.)

Their behaviour differs in the way that the first waits for a fixed time after the *start* of an execution until the *start* of the next execution, and the second waits for a fixed time after the *end* of an execution until the *start* of the next execution. (So the how long an execution takes is relevant.)

You can wrap your `Callable` in a `FutureTask` and pass that to the methods (as it implements `Runnable`) but you have to keep a reference to that `FutureTask` to retrieve the result. Maybe you want to put that in a utility method like this:

```
public Future<V> executeRepeatedly(ScheduledExecutorService executorService, Callable<V> callable, int delay) {
    FutureTask<V> futureTask = new FutureTask<>(callable);
    executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(futureTask, delay, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return futureTask;
}
```

Please use my code only as a suggestion, I didn't test it.

Comment: `scheduleAtFixedRate` won't let you return a future with a generic type, so i have to use `schedule` instead, just need to find a workaround with my code.